# Making a word into a sentinel value in C#

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a program that is a loop with a sentinel value that asks the user to enter a number or enter -99 to end the program and it runs perfectly. If I were to change that -99 to just the word "Quit" is there a certain parameter that I would have to put? For example, if I want to use a letter, I know that I could use:

```
char (undefined parameter) = 'A'
```

But how would I do this with a word? When I simply try to change the value of -99 to Quit, I receive an error as expected.

```
using System;

class Program {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    int sum = 0;
    int counter = 0; 
    int max = Int32.MinValue;
    int min = Int32.MaxValue;
    bool keepGoing = true; 
    while(keepGoing) {
      Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number or enter -99 to stop the program:");
      int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      if (number == -99){
        keepGoing = false;
      } else {
         counter++;
        sum += number;
        if (number >= max) {
          max = number;
        }
        if (number <= min) {
          min = number;
        }
      }
    }
  double average = (double) sum / counter;
  Console.WriteLine($"{counter} numbers were entered.");
  Console.WriteLine("The average is:"  + average);
  Console.WriteLine("The sum is:"  + sum);
  Console.WriteLine("The maximum value is:"  + max);
  Console.WriteLine("The minimum value is:"  + min);
  }
}
```

Comment: `number` is an `int`. It's an `int` because you took the `string` returned by `Console.ReadLine()` and converted it to an int with `Convert.ToInt32(...)`. Think about it. Hint: `Quit` should be a `string`: `"Quit"`, so you need to compare it to a `string`. How might you get that `string`?

Comment: Couldn't I use a method or a function for that? Like if I were to put string Quit = GetQuit(); then have it return Console.ReadLine? I have no idea why is not allowing me to ctrl K these lines of codes in the comments.

Comment: This might be a good place to start https://gist.github.com/ZacharyPatten/798ed612d692a560bdd529367b6a7dbd

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` returns a `string`. You then convert that into an `int`. You want to check if `Console.ReadLine()` returns `"Quit"`. You therefore have to separate the value returned by `Console.ReadLine()` into it's own variable, and check if it equals `"Quit"`. If it does, then you can exit the loop, otherwise you can parse it to an `int` and store it in `number` as you already do.

Comment: Thank you both so much. I am super grateful for the link and the guidance that you have provided me. This was actually way easier than I made it out to be in my head! This is my first time ever coding with C# and my textbook focuses on Java and C++ so it's hard for me to grasp C# as a whole sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to store "Quit" in an int, so the root of your problem is that you have no separation between pulling the string from the console and converting it to an int:

```
  int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  if (number == -99){
    keepGoing = false;
  } else {
     counter++;
```

If you did have a separation, it becomes possible:

```
  string input = Console.ReadLine();
  if (input == "Quit"){
    keepGoing = false;
  } else {
     int number = Convert.ToInt32(input);
     counter++;
```